# Problemas na inserção do Emoji no mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou tendo problemas em inserir emoticons do EMOJI no mySQL, ele insere "????" para cada emoticon.

Minha tabela já esta como utf8mb4_bin como faço pra inserir corretamente? Será o PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

ATENÇÃO:
ESTA RESPOSTA NÃO É DE MINHA AUTORIA, FOI TRADUZIDA DE

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814293/how-to-insert-utf-8-mb4-characteremoji-in-ios5-in-mysql

PARA AUXILIAR O AUTOR DA PERGUNTA, CASO O MESMO NÃO TENHA O CONHECIMENTO DO IDIOMA INGLÊS.

---

Caracteres 4 byte Unicode não são muito usados, então, não é todo aplicativo que tem suporte integral a eles. O mySQL 5.5 funciona bem com eles, se devidamente configurado - veja se os outros componentes funcionam com ele também.

Segue uma lista de algumas coisas a serem verificadas:

Tenha certeza de que a configuração de caracteres padrão de suas tabelas e os campos texto estão convertidos para `uft8mb4`, e a configuração do cliente e caracteres do servidor, ex.

```
ALTER TABLE nomeDaTabela charset=utf8mb4;

MODIFY COLUMN nomeDaTabela VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;

MODIFY COLUMN nomeDaTabela VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

e por ai vai...

Caso seus dados já estiverem em utf8, poderão que ser convertidos para uft8mb4 sem problemas.

Lembre de sempre fazer uma cópia de segurança antes de alterar qualquer coisa.

Alem disso, tenha certeza que seu aplicativo usa a conexão a base de dados com o suporte a caracteres `utf8mb4`. Outra coisa, veja a versão do mySQL que você está utilizando, se for antiga, faça uma atualização dela.

Quando for verificar seus dados a partir de um cliente mySQl, tenha certeza de que seu equipamento pode mostrar emoji e rode um `SET NAMES utf8mb4` antes de usar qualquer query.

Quando cada nível do seu aplicativo puder aceitar os novos caracteres, você poderá usá-los sem qualquer problema.